# How to end a switch that's inside of a switch. Java

Tags: java, case, switch-statement

I am trying to do a switch inside of a switch. Ive gotten it to compile, but the only thing is, every time I run it, I select one of the cases for the first switch, and once I go and select one of the cases for the first switch inside of the switch, it then also asks for me to select a case for the second switch inside of the first switch, then the third and forth, then it ends. How do I either make the entire program start again back at the beginning after selecting the first switch inside of the switch, or end the program. Thanks.

ex.

```
System.out.println("Pick a color.\n");

System.out.println("          1. Red");
System.out.println("          2. Blue");
System.out.println("          3. Yellow");
System.out.println("          4. Green");

Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
int color = kbReader.nextInt();

System.out.println("The color you chose was " + color + ".");
String s1 = kbReader.nextLine();

switch (color)
    {
case 1: //Red
System.out.println("Now enter an integer from 1 through 10.");
int num1 = kbReader.nextInt();

switch (num1)
        {
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 9:
    System.out.println("");

case 2:
case 4:
case 6:
case 8:
case 10:
    System.out.println("");
    break;
        }
case 2: //Blue
System.out.println("Now enter an integer from 1 through 10.");
int num2 = kbReader.nextInt();

switch (num2)
        {
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 9:
    System.out.println("");

case 2:
case 4:
case 6:
case 8:
case 10:
    System.out.println("");

        }
case 3: //Yellow
System.out.println("Now enter an integer from 1 through 10.");
int num3 = kbReader.nextInt();

switch (num3)
        {
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 9:
    System.out.println("");

case 2:
case 4:
case 6:
case 8:
case 10:
    System.out.println("");

        }
case 4: //Green
System.out.println("Now enter an integer from 1 through 10.");
int num4 = kbReader.nextInt();

switch (num4)
        {
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
case 7:
case 9:
    System.out.println("");

case 2:
case 4:
case 6:
case 8:
case 10:
    System.out.println("");     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try putting in more break; statements after each case so you break the current switch. Also, I would refactor your code so you have 1 switch in the main (color), then based on that case, call another method to get input on your integer so you don't nest switch statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put a `break` after the switch statements that are inside the switch statements.

i.e. (for exampe)

```
switch (color) 
    { 
case 1: //Red 
System.out.println("Now enter an integer from 1 through 10."); 
int num1 = kbReader.nextInt(); 

switch (num1) 
        { 
case 1: 
case 3: 
case 5: 
case 7: 
case 9: 
    System.out.println(""); 

case 2: 
case 4: 
case 6: 
case 8: 
case 10: 
    System.out.println(""); 
    break; 
        } 

break;  <--- this is the addition
case 2: //Blue
```

Alternatively (and would make the whole thing more readable) put those switches into another function

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using break statement
you should give a break; statement after your case finish execution.
like this.
    case 1:
     break;

if you do not give break statement then it will execute sequentially .After first switch it will go to the next switch and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap any of the switches inside a conditional loop (while / do-while) and when it reaches the end, if you condition isn't achieved (say you want variable **done** to be *true*), the switch will repeat.

Also, you can use *break;* after the print functions in the switches to stop continuing the switch options.

To repeat the entire program, wrap it inside a while or do-while loop.